# The program is not terminating

Tags: c, function, output, runtime-error, terminate

```
#include<stdio.h>

int reverse(int );

int main()`
{
    int num,rem,r;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    r=reverse(num);
    r=reverse(num);
    return 0;
}

int reverse(int num)
{
    int rem,rev=0;
    while(num>=0)
    {
        rem=num%10;
        rev=rev*10+rem;
        num=num/10;
    }
    return rev;
}
```

Its not showing any errors and after entering the number the program stay still, its neither showing any output nor terminating

Comment: The answer will become clear to you if you place a `printf("%d\n", num);` inside the `while` loop in your `reverse()` function. `num` will never drop below 0, thus the condition of the while loop is always true.

Comment: 0/10 is still 0 and 0>=0 is true

Comment: You should check if `scanf` succeeds. If you suspect the loop does not terminate, you should add debug print inside the loop, or use debugger and set a breakpoint there.

Answer (score 1):

You have not used printf for output.

```
r = reverse(num);
printf("%d",r);
return 0;
```

Use this.
And also while condition should be

```
 while (num > 0)
```

There is no need to call reverse function twice as well.